# How to use Fortran interface to call a C function which contains user defined type

Tags: c, interface, fortran, user-defined-types, magma

In fact, I want to call magma from fortran. So I add magma.lib and create an interface to use the C fuction of magma:

```
Interface
      Integer function magma_dpotrf(uplo, n, a, lda, info) BIND (C, NAME="magma_dpotrf")
        use iso_c_binding
        Implicit none
        !character (c_char), value :: uplo????
        integer (c_int), value ::n
        real (c_double) ::a(*)
        integer (c_int), value ::lda
        integer (c_int)::info
      end function
   end Interface
```

But the parameter uplo is a user defined type
In C code (magma_uplo_t uplo):

```
typedef enum {
    MagmaUpper         = 121,
    MagmaLower         = 122,
    MagmaUpperLower    = 123,
    MagmaFull          = 123,  /* lascl, laset */
    MagmaHessenberg    = 124   /* lascl */
} magma_uplo_t;

magma_int_t
magma_dpotrf(
    magma_uplo_t uplo, magma_int_t n,
    double *A, magma_int_t lda,
    magma_int_t *info);
```

magma_int_t = int, Does anyone knows how to create interface for it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`magma_uplo_t` is an enumeration. There is some support for them in Fortran 2003 but you can quite safely assume it is an `integer(c_int)` which can take the values from 121 to 124. And in your case it is passed by value.

```
integer(c_int), value :: uplo
```

You can actually create the constants using a Fortran 2003 enumeration

```
 enum, bind( C )
    enumerator :: MagmaUpper         = 121, &
                  MagmaLower         = 122, &
                  MagmaUpperLower    = 123, &
                  MagmaFull          = 123, &
                  MagmaHessenberg    = 124
  end enum
```

but the variable and then you can also try `integer(kind=kind(MagmaUpper))` to be completely safe. This will survive things like the GCC's `--short-enums` option.

Answer (score 0):

Also digged before, but not satisfied yet. How about these solutions ...?

!https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/named-enum-bind-c/m-p/1103221

```
    use iso_c_binding
#if NAMED_ENUM
      enum, bind(c) :: color
        enumerator :: red = 4, blue = 9
        enumerator yellow
      end enum
#else
      enum, bind(c)
        enumerator :: red = 4, blue = 9
        enumerator yellow
      end enum
#endif
```

From http://computer-programming-forum.com/49-fortran/cfa557a9177328c6.htm
expression to a type(ENUM2) variable is not allowed.
Here is the source code:

```
program enums
   type enum1
      integer :: value
   end type enum1
   type enum2
      integer :: value
   end type enum2
   type(enum1), parameter :: v1 = enum1(1)
   type(enum1), parameter :: v2 = enum1(2)
   type(enum2), parameter :: w1 = enum2(1)
   type(enum2), parameter :: w2 = enum2(2)
   type(enum1) :: var1
   type(enum2) :: var2
   var1 = v1
   var2 = w1
   write(*,*) var1, var2
   var1 = w1
   var2 = v1
   write(*,*) var1, var2
   stop
end program
```

Comment: I do not understand how this changes things from the existing answer and how it answers how to pass the stuff to a C function. I do not actually see how the two code samples are connected. Be aware that the other link is to a discussion from 2004 when the features from Fortran 2003 were not available while the code in the first code sample uses these features. Note that the `integer :: value` is not completely safe because a C enum can be a different kind of `int`.